# Is an implicit copyright license sublicensable?

Tags: copyright, england-and-wales

I am involved with a small magazine owned by a limited company in England.  It has been in print for a little over a century and contains many articles written by identifiable third parties.  In many cases, the authors are now dead or not readily traceable, though the content remains in copyright.  The authors were never asked to agree any written licensing agreement, nor to assign copyright to us, nevertheless an implicit licence must have been granted.  We are trying to understand what, in broad terms, this implicit licence allows us to do.

Clearly we can assume that by submitting the article for print, the author implicitly licensed use of the article to us for that purpose.  And the magazine has a long history of reprinting notable articles, sometimes in the magazine, sometimes in other formats, and I think we can *probably* assume an author will have known that was the expectation when they submitted the article.  But can we allow authorise a third party to republish the article, perhaps on a website?

Can we assume that this sort of implicit licence is a non-exclusive, transferable, sublicensable one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No

A court will imply terms into a contract only to the extent that they are necessary to make the contract effective. See [BP Refinery (Westernport) Pty Ltd v Shire of Hastings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BP_Refinery_(Westernport)_Pty_Ltd_v_Shire_of_Hastings#:%7E:text=BP%20Refinery%20(Westernport)%20Pty%20Ltd%20v%20Shire%20of%20Hastings%20is,intentions%20of%20the%20contracting%20parties.) [1977] UKPC 13.

Your contract was for the author to provide an article for publication, and for you to pay them. There is no need to imply a term that the article can be republished or put on a website to give effect to that contract. You don’t need exclusivity, transferability, or sub-license-ability to perform your functions under the contract.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean the company cannot put an archive of its old issues online or, say, sell them on a DVD, if they contain content still in copyright?  (Perhaps this should be a separate question?)

Comment: Sounds like a seperate question